# Why "list.foreach(println(_ + "s"))" cannot work?

Tags: scala

As the title describes, the code followed compiles successfully:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
list.foreach(println(_))
```

But if I replace the second line with

```
list.foreach(println(_ + "test"))
```

compilation shows error with

```
 missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => x$2.$plus("ss"))
    list.foreach(println(_ + "ss"))
```

Again I replace the second with

```
list.foreach(number => println(number + "test"))
```

it works successfully again.
I don't know why it happens. I guess maybe the `_`'s usage is wrong.

Comment: Please add the error logs here

Comment: @JohnJoe This is Scala code, not Java.

Comment: you should be doing `list.foreach(x => println(x + "test"))` . I am looking for explanation myself as well though